# How to store data from facebook to local variable?

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk

Im using the SDK 3 by facebook, and to store the facebook id i am doing this:

```
$facebook_id = $user;
```

Which works a treat! However... i cannot access individual items in the array, like i remember with the previous SDK you could do:

$first_name = $me['first_name'];

However, i have tried that, and $user['first_name'] and stuff but getting no where! I cant find any documentation of this either on their dev website or on the internet :/

Many thanks.
Ian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like $user is just the Facebook User ID that you get through the authentication flow.  If you want to get user info, you need to make a separate Graph call, like so:

```
$res = $facebook->api('/me');
$first_name = $res['first_name'];
```